# How to get the length of a row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas frame

```
idx col1    col2    col3    col4
0    a       b        c       d
1    d       a
2    a
3    g       f        f
```

I want to get length of row
How can i get the correct count as follow?

```
idx   length
0       4
1       2
2       1
3       3
```

[image]

Comment: Append the row data into a list and take the list length?

Comment: if idx is an index and the blank spaces are `np.nan` ,  this is `df.count` on `axis=1`

Comment: Thanks you. I have added image my question. I want to get expected length as image.